# Drupal 7 views add one field as a URL to another

Tags: views, entities

I am using Drupal 7. I have a view where i filer a certain content type say "A" and display the below 2 fields 
  Content: Title
  Content: File attachments

My File attachment formatter is set "Url to file".

What i am trying to achieve is to make 'Title' as a link with the 'File Attachment' URL

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- for the Title, set it 'Exclude from display'
- for the File attachments, 'Rewrite the output of this field' using the token for Title

Make sure the Title field appears above the file attachment, or the file attachment won't recognize it as a valid token when rewriting the output

Comment: Great, worked fine!